# Formulating a problem as an LP and a max flow problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am still having troubles formulating both LP and max flow problems. So I would really appreciate it if somebody could show me how to do that for this example:

> 34 female and 62 male students have to form pairs of two.
>   Each student makes a list of partners (s)he would like to work with.
>   Each male student has only females on his list, each female student has only males on her list.
>   We want to make pairs in such a way that there are as many pairs of students who like eachother as possible.

I would be very grateful if someone could formulate this as an LP problem and as a max flow problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Consider a bipartite graph with vertices $B \cup G$, with boys represented by $B$ and girls by $G$. Connect $b \in B$ to $g \in G$ iff $b$ and $g$ like each other. Each of these edges will have capacity 1.

Now add a source connected to all of $B$ and a sink connected to all of $G$. Can you finish this?